# forJoin for dynamic amount of requests not printing when done

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

So I'm using forkJoin to complete a dynamic amount of requests. It's working great, but I'm not getting my console log when subscribing to the forkJoin? All the examples I've seen just do a basic subscribe like I am, so I'm not really understanding why it isn't working.

I've added the DataService calls also for more clarity. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong there and that's why the forkJoin isn't working?

Here is my code:

```
let requests = [];
newAdds.forEach(ele => {
    requests.push(this._dataService.add(ID1, ID2));
});

forkJoin(requests).subscribe(ret => {
    console.log(ret);
  }
);

 add(id1, id2) {
    class Add{
      ID1: number;
      ID2: string;
    };
    let data = new Add();
    data.ID1 = id1;
    data.ID2 = id2;


    let cmd = "Add";
    return this.put(this.urlAdmin() + cmd, data);
  }


protected put(cmd: string, body: any) {
 let headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

 return this._http.put(cmd, body, {
   headers: headers
 });
}
```

Comment: Read more on forkJoin https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin It will only emit when all the request emits the value. Even if one request fails, it won't emit anything and you won't see console logging your message. Also I would suggest to monitor your network request to have more clarity on which all requests are getting failed/blocked

Comment: None of the calls fail though?

Comment: I've added some additional information, perhaps that will help identify the issue

Answer (score 1):

`forkJoin` will only emit *if and only if* **all** observables have completed.

This one example will never emit (interval never ends)

```
forkJoin([interval(1000), interval(2000)]).subscribe(console.log); // won't emit
```

---

This example will emit [0, 0] value after 2000ms.

```
forkJoin([timer(1000), timer(2000)]).subscribe(console.log); // emit [0,0]
```

---

If one observable does't emit a single value but completes, forkJoin won't emit

```
forkJoin(of()).subscribe(console.log) // won't emit
```

---

If at least 1 observable throws an error, `forkJoin` will never complete.

```
forkJoin([of(1), throwError(1)]).subscribe(console.log); // will never emit
```

[ForkJoin doc](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin)

Comment: None of my calls fail though?

Comment: It's either a request failing or never completing. Please check every of your requests.

Comment: I've added some additional information, perhaps that will help identify the issue